# When is the closure of a manifold a manifold with boundary?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm looking for conditions that ensure the closure of an embedded manifold is a manifold with boundary.

The specific case I'm interested is as follows. Consider an oriented $C^1$ surface ${\cal S}$ in $\Bbb R^3$ such that its closure is known to be a $C^0$ surface with boundary. Moreover, suppose we know that the normal to ${\cal S}$ has a continuous extension to the closure. Does this imply that the closure is a $C^1$ manifold with boundary?

Comment: But for instance, what about a plane domain in {z=0}, interior to a continuous nondifferentiable curve?

Comment: Ah, good one. Thanks for the counterexample! Going back to the larger question of what conditions are necessary to ensure the closure is a $C^1$ surface, what if we also assume that the boundary is a $C^1$ curve. Is that enough to ensure the closure is a $C^1$ manifold?

Comment: Take a $C^1$ function on $(0,1]$ which has a continuous but not differentiable extension to $[0,1]$. Now let the manifold be the open “rounded” square (the corners rounded smoothly), and move its $z$ coordinate by that function w.r.t. the $x$-coordinate: The normal has a continuous extension to the boundary, the boundary is a $C^1$-curve, but the manifold is not smoother than continuous at the boundary

Comment: @MartinVäth Could you give more details? it is nor clear to me... thx

Comment: @MartinVäth Why don't you write down your comment as an answer? I'll upvote it.

Comment: I realized that my example is not correct without additional work: The boundary is normally not $C^1$ at $x=0$. It might be possible to save the example by rounding the corners in a very special way, but it needs more consideration.

Comment: I think that adding the condition that the boundary is a $C^1$ curve, then it is true. The condition that  the normal  extends to a continuous $\nu: \overline S\to\mathbb R^3$  should imply by the local inverse theorem  that  $\overline S$ is locally a graph of a $C^1$ function defined  on a  $C^1$ manifold with boundary  in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @PietroMajer This is my intuition as well, but it is unclear to me exactly how to use the local inverse theorem here since $\bar{\cal S}$ is closed and this theorem deals with open sets. If you know how the details would go, I'd be grateful if you could writeup an answer. If you do, it might be better to do so under this other post as it asks specifically this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464387/is-a-c1-surface-with-c1-boundary-and-uniformly-continuous-normal-a-manifol?noredirect=1#comment1206121_464387