# Is a $C^1$ surface with $C^1$ boundary and uniformly continuous normal a manifold with boundary?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Consider an oriented $C^1$ surface ${\cal S}$ whose closure is a $C^0$ surface with boundary whose boundary is a $C^1$ curve. If the normal to ${\cal S}$ is uniformly continuous, so that it has a continuous extension to the closure of ${\cal S}$, does this imply that the closure of ${\cal S}$ is a $C^1$ manifold with boundary?

Comment: I suspect this is related to your other question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464331/when-is-the-closure-of-a-manifold-a-manifold-with-boundary  i.e. you are interested in 2-manifolds in $\mathbb R^3$.